# MySQL Retrieve rows that includes also those not found by query

Tags: php, mysql

A have php webpage that retrieves data from a mysql database.
I would like to know how to retrieve also rows that is not found on query.
Something like this

[image]

Those that have 0 under the 'Player' column means they have no transaction let's say on the data is for year 2014. This is kind of a report / monitoring of Agents that was made on MS Excel.
I would like to improve their lives therefore, I'm creating a webpage equivalent of this, so that anywhere, anytime it can be accessed thru our VPN. Not bad for a small business company.

What SQL query can achieve this?

My Sql query so far

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.`a_id`,'TOTAL') AS 
ALLGAMES, a.`risk`, 
COUNT(DISTINCT b.`player_id`) AS 'Player',
COUNT(`bet_id`) AS 'Qty',
SUM(`bet_amount`) AS Bet,
SUM(b.`zen_ss`) AS Gain,
SUM(`agent_ss`) AS AgentGain,
SUM(`sa_ss`) AS SAGain FROM `bet` b 
LEFT JOIN `agent` a ON b.`a_id`=a.`a_id` 
LEFT JOIN `player` p ON b.`player_id`=p.`player_id` 
LEFT JOIN `match` m ON b.`match_id`=m.`match_id` 
LEFT JOIN `game_type` gt ON b.`game_type_id`=gt.`game_type_id` 
LEFT JOIN `category` c ON b.`league_id`=c.`league_id` 
LEFT JOIN `bet_type` bt ON b.`bet_type_id`=bt.`bet_type_id` 
WHERE `bet_id`>0 GROUP BY b.`a_id` WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: well to start with, `agent` would need to be the first table in your query, with the others left joined to that.

Comment: tested it on sql fiddle but there are 2 occurence of a_id (agent id)s being returned a_id 16 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/056a3/1

Comment: its an illusion. the last row is what 'with rollup' is putting there

Answer (score 0):

The first table on your query should be the agent table, also the group by of the query should be changed to the agent id, all the other left joins should follow after the agent table.

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.`a_id`,'TOTAL') AS 
ALLGAMES, a.`risk`, 
COUNT(DISTINCT b.`player_id`) AS 'Player',
COUNT(`bet_id`) AS 'Qty',
SUM(`bet_amount`) AS Bet,
SUM(b.`zen_ss`) AS Gain,
SUM(`agent_ss`) AS AgentGain,
SUM(`sa_ss`) AS SAGain FROM `agent` a
LEFT JOIN `bet` b ON b.`a_id`=a.`a_id` AND `b`.`bet_id`>0
LEFT JOIN `player` p ON b.`player_id`=p.`player_id` 
LEFT JOIN `match` m ON b.`match_id`=m.`match_id` 
LEFT JOIN `game_type` gt ON b.`game_type_id`=gt.`game_type_id` 
LEFT JOIN `category` c ON b.`league_id`=c.`league_id` 
LEFT JOIN `bet_type` bt ON b.`bet_type_id`=bt.`bet_type_id` 
GROUP BY a.`a_id`
```

Comment: I dont think all agents are being returned by the query. currently I have 19 agents but the query displays only 17.

Comment: tested it on sql fiddle but there are 2 occurence of a_id (agent id)s being returned a_id 16 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/056a3/1

Comment: the with rollup screwed the query, I edited my answer and created a demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/056a3/13

Comment: Looks great. But I noticed that when you add WHERE conditions, the other a ids are gone again.. like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/056a3/20